# How to determine the name of a running QEMU virtual machine?

Tags: qemu

I would like to determine the name of a QEMU VM I started with:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 4096 -smp 1 \
  -net user -net nic,model=virtio -boot menu=on \
  -drive file=guixsd-usb-install-0.13.0.x86_64-linux.img \
-drive file=guixsd.img
```

(per the [GuixSD VM installation guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/guix/manual/html_node/Installing-GuixSD-in-a-VM.html)). The reason for my desire to determine the VM's name is so that I can save its machine state (similarly to how one can for a VirtualBox VM) using the `savevm` command. I have tried using:

```
virsh -c qemu:///system list
```

but this returns:

```
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
```

likewise running:

```
ps -ef | grep qemu-system-x86_64
```

(per [this AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/444849/how-to-list-all-virtual-machines-created-using-qemu-system-x86-64)) isn't helpful because of the command I used to start the VM. If it is somehow relevant I am running Gentoo Linux as my host OS.

Comment: Starting the virtual machine like you did is not recognized by virsh (and the VM does not have a name). You'ld have to create a domain (either by `virsh create`or `virsh define` from an XML file). `virsh`is an interface to `libvirt`and does not directly deal with qemu or other hypervisors like kvm, xen, ... See `man virsh`.

Answer (score 1):

`virsh` is the CLI tool to operate the `libvirt` virtualisation management framework. In that framework, you would define virtual machines using any of the hypervisor supported by `libvirt` including `qemu`, `xen`, `virtualbox` via the management interface.

`libvirt` provides with a level of abstraction above things like `qemu`. With it, you would not start `qemu` directly. Instead `libvirt` would start `qemu` with some special options that allows to interact with `qemu`.

For instance, on my system, `libvirt` started qemu with those parameters for one it its VMs:

```
qemu-system-x86_64  -enable-kvm \
                    -name freebsd11.0 -S \
                    -machine pc-i440fx-wily,accel=kvm,usb=off \
                    -cpu Nehalem \
                    -m 1536 \
                    -realtime mlock=off \
                    -smp 3,sockets=3,cores=1,threads=1 \
                    -uuid 82f3448e-2767-46b1-a7d1-7072184ef924 \
                    -no-user-config \
                    -nodefaults \
                    -chardev socket,id=charmonitor,path=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/domain-freebsd11.0/monitor.sock,server,nowait \
                    -mon chardev=charmonitor,id=monitor,mode=control \
                    -rtc base=utc,driftfix=slew \
                    -global kvm-pit.lost_tick_policy=discard \
                    -no-hpet \
                    -no-shutdown \
                    -global PIIX4_PM.disable_s3=1 \
                    -global PIIX4_PM.disable_s4=1 \
                    -boot strict=on \
                    -device ich9-usb-ehci1,id=usb,bus=pci.0,addr=0x6.0x7 \
                    -device ich9-usb-uhci1,masterbus=usb.0,firstport=0,bus=pci.0,multifunction=on,addr=0x6 \
                    -device ich9-usb-uhci2,masterbus=usb.0,firstport=2,bus=pci.0,addr=0x6.0x1 \
                    -device ich9-usb-uhci3,masterbus=usb.0,firstport=4,bus=pci.0,addr=0x6.0x2 \
                    -device virtio-serial-pci,id=virtio-serial0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x5 \
                    -drive file=/home/chazelas/Downloads/FreeBSD-11.0-RC1-amd64.qcow2,format=qcow2,if=none,id=drive-virtio-disk0 \
                    -device virtio-blk-pci,scsi=off,bus=pci.0,addr=0x7,drive=drive-virtio-disk0,id=virtio-disk0,bootindex=1 \
                    -netdev tap,fd=26,id=hostnet0,vhost=on,vhostfd=28 \
                    -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=hostnet0,id=net0,mac=52:54:00:11:8a:53,bus=pci.0,addr=0x3 \
                    -chardev pty,id=charserial0 \
                    -device isa-serial,chardev=charserial0,id=serial0 \
                    -chardev spicevmc,id=charchannel0,name=vdagent \
                    -device virtserialport,bus=virtio-serial0.0,nr=1,chardev=charchannel0,id=channel0,name=com.redhat.spice.0 \
                    -spice port=5900,addr=127.0.0.1,disable-ticketing,image-compression=off,seamless-migration=on \
                    -device qxl-vga,id=video0,ram_size=67108864,vram_size=67108864,vgamem_mb=16,bus=pci.0,addr=0x2 \
                    -device intel-hda,id=sound0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x4 \
                    -device hda-duplex,id=sound0-codec0,bus=sound0.0,cad=0 \
                    -chardev spicevmc,id=charredir0,name=usbredir \
                    -device usb-redir,chardev=charredir0,id=redir0 \
                    -chardev spicevmc,id=charredir1,name=usbredir \
                    -device usb-redir,chardev=charredir1,id=redir1 \
                    -device virtio-balloon-pci,id=balloon0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x8 \
                    -msg timestamp=on
```

Most of that is specification of the virtual hardware of the virtual machine, but you also see:

```
-chardev socket,id=charmonitor,path=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/domain-freebsd11.0/monitor.sock,server,nowait 
-mon chardev=charmonitor,id=monitor,mode=control
```

Which specifies a channel with which `libvirt` can interact with `qemu` (using some JSON-based *machine* protocol)

But you wouldn't be using that directly. You would issue `virsh` commands like `virsh shutdown`. `virsh` would transmit those to the `libvirtd` daemon which in turn would translate it to `qemu` specific instructions using that channel.

In your case, though, you're not using `libvirt`. You've not defined a VM using `virt-manager` or `virt-install` (or `virsh define/create`). Instead you've started `qemu` manually by yourself.

`libvirt`, if it's installed has no knowledge of that VM. So there's no point trying to use `virsh` to interact with it.

The way you've started `qemu`, you've not specified any particular *monitor* channel to interact with it, so you'll get the default.

By default, you'll typically get the *SDL* graphics console.

In it, you can type <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+2</kbd> to get the *human* monitor interface. That's a command line interface. You'll see a

```
 (qemu)
```

prompt where you can enter commands. Try `help` for a summary.

If you had given a *name* to your VM with `-name`, you'd be able to retrieve it with the `info name` command there.

That's where you'd run your `savevm` qemu command. But to use the `savevm` command, AFAIK, you have to have at least one `qcow2` disk image attached to the VM which doesn't seem to be your case.

To suspend and save the state of the VM, you could do (at the `(qemu)` prompt):

```
migrate "exec:gzip>/path/to/savedstate.gz"
```

Which would suspend the VM and save the compressed state to a file. And then, you can `quit` and later bring back the VM from that saved state by adding a `-incoming 'exec:gunzip</path/to/savestate.gz'` to your `qemu-system` command line.

There's a whole lot of things you can do if you know qemu well, but if you want to make your life easier, you'd probably use management wrappers around qemu like libvirt.